# How to programatically construct a format string for struct.unpack?

Tags: python

I'm attempting to read and parse a binary file with Python.

The issue is that the data in the file can be in little-endian or big-endian format, as well as 32- or 64-bit values.   In the file header there are a few bytes that specify the data format and size. Let's assume that I've read these in and I know the format and size, and I try to construct a format string as follows:

```
    if (bitOrder == 1):      # little-endian format
        strData = '<'
    elif (bitOrder == 2):    # bit-endian format
        strData = '>'

    if (dataSize == 1):      # 32-bit data
        strLen = 'L'
    elif (dataSize == 2):
        strLen = 'q'

    strFormat = strData + strLen
    struct.unpack(strFormat, buf)
```

When I do this I get the error: `"struct.error: unpack requires a string argument of length 2"`, yet if I write `struct.unpack('<L', buf)` I get the expected result.

On an interactive shell, if I run `type(strFormat)` I get the result `<type, 'str'>` and when I run `len(strFormat)` I get a result of `2`.

So, being relatively new to Python, I have the following questions:

1. Is not `str` the same as a string?  If not, how do I convert between the two?
2. How would I correctly construct the format string for use in an `unpack` function?

------ edit ------
to address comments:

1. at this time I'm using python-2.7 due to constraints of other projects.
2. I'm trying to avoid posting my code (its several hundred lines long), however here is an interact python (run from inside emacs, if that matters) that shows the behaviour I'm experiencing:

   ```
   Python 2.7.5 (default, Jun 17 2014, 18:11:42) 
   [GCC 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-16)] on linux2
   Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
   >>> >>> >>> >>> 
   >>> import array
   >>> import struct
   >>> header = array.array('B',[0x7f, 0x45, 0x4c, 0x46, 0x02, 0x01, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x00,0x3e, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x40, 0x04, 0x40, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x40, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x70, 0x11, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x40, 0x00, 0x38, 0x00, 0x09, 0x00, 0x40, 0x00, 0x1e, 0x00, 0x1b, 0x00])
   >>> entry = header[24:32]
   >>> phoff = header[32:40]
   >>> shoff = header[40:48]
   >>> strData = '<'
   >>> strLen = 'H'
   >>> strFormat = strData + strLen
   >>> print strFormat
   <H
   >>> type(strFormat)
   <type 'str'>
   >>> len(strFormat)
   2
   >>> temp = struct.unpack(strFormat, entry)
   Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   struct.error: unpack requires a string argument of length 2
   >>>
   ```
3. fixed types in original code.

Comment: Could you post your actual code?  What you have here obviously isn't it, as you're missing the colons in the second `if` block.  (Also, is this Python 2 or Python 3?)

Comment: Also, a suggestion: Try debugging your code by printing `bitOrder`, `dataSize`, and `strFormat` just before the call to `struct.unpack`.  It's possible that one of those is taking an unexpected value.

Comment: What's `len(buf)`?  That's what `unpack` is complaining about -- and not with the code you're showing; `L` requires a length 4, `q` requires a length 8 -- neither requires a length `2`.  `struct.calcsize(strFormat)` will tell you how many bytes `strFormat` requires on your platform, and `len(buf)` must `==` exactly that number of bytes.

Comment: As for your Qs 1 and 2, an `str` is indeed a string, and concatenating parts is one valid way to build it.  Your error(s) must be in other parts of the code you're not showing (besides the syntax error in lack of colons which @jwodder notices, and guarantees 100% that you're **not** showing us the actual code you're running -- thus making helping you very, very hard!-).

Comment: Why are you setting `strLen = 'H'` in the second example?  `H` is for 2-byte integers, and is not one of the `strLen` values you use in your first code snippet.

Comment: Because I'm an idiot (well only on those days that end in 'y' :)).  It was an error in decision logic on which the second character was based.  Also, there were a bit of personal bias (coming from a C/C++ background) that when the error was referring to string I took that as the first argument, naively assuming the second argument would have a type of array or something.  Thus I focused in on the first argument being the source of the error.   Also, to directly answer jwodder's query the first example and the second example were taken from different snap-shots of my effort to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going by the interactive session, your problem would appear to be this:

```
temp = struct.unpack(strFormat, entry)
```

Earlier, you said:

```
entry = header[24:32]
```

`entry` is 8 bytes long, but `strFormat` says it should be 2 bytes long.  That's what `struct` is complaining about.

It should also be a `bytes` object (`str` under 2.x), not an `array.array`.